# append huge volume of text to javafx TextArea from another thread (i.e. javafx task)

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I'm creating a simple text editor application like ms notepad using JavaFX. I want it to handle large files maximum of 10mb, to do this I have created a task using the JavaFX concurrent package. The task will read the file using a buffered reader and append it to the text area.
My problem is that when I run the task with small files like 8kb to 10kb it works perfectly but when I increase the file size UI starts freezing and after reading few lines it stops working and I have to force stop the program.

Here is the code of task I have created...

```
public class ReadFile extends Task<String> {

private TextArea writingPad;
private File source;

public ReadFile(TextArea writingPad, File source) {
    this.writingPad = writingPad;
    this.source = source;
}

@Override
protected String call() throws Exception {
    if (source != null && Files.exists(source.toPath())) {
        if (source.isFile()) {
            if (source.canRead()) {
                if ((source.length() / (1024 * 1024)) <= 10) {
                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source.getAbsolutePath()))) {
                        writingPad.clear();
                        updateTitle("Reading " + source.getName() + "...");

                        int workDone = 0;
                        char[] buffer = new char[8192];
                        int read;
                        while ((read = reader.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) >= 0) {
                            writingPad.appendText(String.valueof(buffer, 0, 8192));
                            workDone += read;
                            updateProgress(workDone, source.length());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {

                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File is loo large.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Can't read file.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Is a directory.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Is null");
    }
    return null;
}}
```

The above code throws exceptions like `NullPointerException` and `IndexOuofBoundException` so to  solve this exception i have used this -> `Platform.runLater(() -> writingPad.appendText(String.valueOf(buffer, 0, finalread))); Thread.sleep(100);` method, but it also doesn't help me to achieve my goal properly. As it has solved the problem of exception but it takes too much time to read even small files and for large files problem is still the same. I have searched the internet but I didn't get any solution which can solve my problem.

So here is what I want:-

- I want an effective and efficient way to read a text file (max size
  10mb) and display its content in a text area.
- The whole process of reading and writing is going to take place
  from another thread (i.e a JavaFX task) so UI should not freeze
  during the process.
- As my application is a text editor so, no other UI component like
  listview is going to be helpful.

Please suggest me a simple and easy solution as I'm new to JavaFX and multithreading.

Thanks

Comment: _I'm new to JavaFX and multithreading_ then work through a tutorial an javafx basics, in particular multithreading, practice what you learn in simple examples, increase complexity until you are fit to takle a broad problem :) When stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected. That said: you can try to read the file in bunches (in the background) and publish those bunches on the fx application thread.

Comment: whatever you do, you __must not__ change a node that's in an active scenegraph (that implies not changing any of its properties) off the fx application thread

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from the javadoc of the Task class:

"An implementation of Task must override the call() method. This method is invoked on the background thread. Any state which is used in this method must be safe to read and write from a background thread. For example, manipulating a live scene graph from this method is unsafe and will result in runtime exceptions."

This should make it clear why your code is completely wrong.